Which Premchand novels are written in Hindi and which in Urdu?
This answer only discusses short stories
I wanted to know about which of Premchand's novels are written in Hindi or in Urdu. Like Godaan, Nirmala, Gaban, Rangbhoomi, etc. Thanks.
